# not sure why a Proc would be used here - not getting something simple

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, proc

I understand the concept of a proc but sometime I see code like this (take from rails guide for validation http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#using-if-and-unless-with-a-proc):

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :normalize_card_number,
    :if => Proc.new { |order| order.paid_with_card? }
end
```

it seems this could be more simply written as:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :normalize_card_number, :if => :paid_with_card? 
end
```

What am I not getting about the advantage of using a Proc here?

thx in advance

Comment: In this case they are equivalent.  I think the original example was done to illustrate that you can pass a Proc object and that it receives the object being validated.  This might be useful if your validation logic was not an instance method or if it was simple enough to write inline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In simple cases they are equivalent, but procs allow far more versatility without requiring a method to be defined simply for a validation if check.

Imagine this:

```
before_save :nuke, :if => Proc.new { |model| !model.nuked? && model.nukable? && model.region.nukable? }
```

You can always write that check in an instance method and reference it with a symbol, but for cases where the specific logic is only in the :if, it is valid to keep it in a proc.

Comment: very nice.  This is exactly the reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

They are equivalent if the receiver of the method is the object being validated. This isn't *exactly* how the ActiveModel validators work, but the concept is similar:

Calling `to_proc` on a symbol `:sym` gives you the functional equivalent of ->(x){ x.sym } - the symbol is sent as a message to the argument of the proc. Calling `to_proc` on a proc simply returns itself, so you can pass either a symbol or proc into a method and guarantee a proc:

```
def return_a_proc(symbol_or_proc)
  symbol_or_proc.to_proc
end
```

In cases where the model instance is not the receiver, e.g. the validation method takes the model as an argument, or as in Daniel Evans' example, you need to explicitly construct the proc to specify what should be done with the proc's argument.